# Can't retrieve data from MS SQL with PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I use PDO on my local computer to connect to MS SQL server to use prepare statements. The driver is installed properly and can connect to database. Here's the code:

```
try {
    $con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$host};Database={$db_name}", $username, $password);
    }
catch(PDOException $exception){
echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT TOP 10 ClientID FROM CLIENT";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->rowCount();
print $num;
```

From SSMS the query returns as it should, but nothing from the code as it prints -1 as the result of `$num`. If i change the query to `SELECT @@VERSION` it prints the version properly but not my query. My query is right from SSMS and PDO can connect to server but can't figure out where the problem is it's so frustrating please help.

Comment: From the documentation: [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on [...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try :

```
try {
    $con = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server={$host};Database={$db_name}", $username, $password);
    }
catch(PDOException $exception){
echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}

$query = "SELECT TOP 10 ClientID FROM CLIENT";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$num = count($rows);
print $num;

// To print results :
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row["ClientID"] . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Anyway how do I print the rows though? My code was to extract the row before to print it in a formatted table:

Comment: `if($num>0){ 
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  extract($row);
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>{$Date}</td>";`